# Break - wrong place?

Tags: php

I have just come across this code:

```
function test(){

//...

if ( $profilerule == "profile" and $operator != "=" ) {
                verbatimlogit('false');
                break;
}

//...

}
```

Is it just me or will that break not work there?! There isn't even a loop. A continue work either, right?

I just want a confirmation here as I am pretty sure this is the case.

Comment: That snippet looks like the developer didn't know the difference between break; and return;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PHP docs of the `break` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), this would be an invalid structure (unless there was a loop in the code you removed.)

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Documentation](http://us.php.net/break):

> `break` ends execution of the current
>   `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do`-`while` or
>   `switch` structure.

So yes, inside an `if`, it's invalid (unless that `if` is within one of the above structures).

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you're trying to end execution of the function, you'd probably just want to use the return() statement.

http://us.php.net/return